# After refreshing div through ajax, event listeners doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This is the reload button, which is floating on the page bottom, it's not included in the div #main-content that gets refreshed after clicking it:

```
<div id="reload-maincontent" data-action="rdm01">
    <button class="hellofresh hellofresh--darkred--shadowed--floating rd2" type="button">
        <div class="c-ripple js-ripple">
            <span class="c-ripple__circle"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="reloadMaincontent-innertext" style="font-weight:500;"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The following script will fire off the div reload of #main-content:

```
$(document).on("click", '#reload-maincontent', reloadMaincontentCollectorsPage);
function reloadMaincontentCollectorsPage() {
    var reloadContent = location.href + " #main--content";

    $("#main--content").css( "opacity","0" );
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#main--content").load(reloadContent)
        .css( "opacity","1" );
    }, 600);
    $(this).removeClass('toggleInfo');
};
```

If I click the button to reload the div, it works fine but event listeners in that div that got refreshed aren't working anymore. Following the div that gets refreshed after clicking the button:

```
<div id="main--content">

    <div class="a-can lt rd10 ovhid">
        <div class="tools">
            <div id="add-cans" data-catid="..." class="ac-option">
                <p>
                    <i class="material-icons md-18">add</i> add a can
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

There are many of this structure, they are showing different pictures from the database. When I click on the #add-cans div the following script should fire off, but it doesn't work anymore after the refresh:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-catid]', getCanaddInformation);
function getCanaddInformation() {
    var catid = $(this).data("catid");
    var catName = $(this).data("cadd-catname");
    var catCount = $(this).data("cadd-currcans");

    $('#get-catname-uploader').text(catName);
    $('#addcan-catid').val(catid);
}
```

The scripts are included in the head tag right under the jQuery.

Comment: You need to delegate like you did with #reload-maincontent

Comment: I am delegating all event listeners but it still doesn't work

Comment: Impossiblie. There must be something else...for further help you should provide more code...

Comment: *«...but event listeners in that div that got refreshed »* -- Is that code for the delegated click event **within** the refreshed div??? If so, can't you just place it elsewhere?

Comment: Look, after I click the reload button a specific div #main-content gets reloaded. #main-content includes insertions from a database and after refreshing this div it shows more data. But event listeners from buttons in that refreshed div doesn't work anymore and I can't place them elsewhere

Comment: That is unclear without the HTML. Please post it for us to know what is refreshed and where the scripts are located...

Comment: I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure this is the whole issue... But I think `$(this)` isn't defined in your functions, as nothing bind an element to the function. Try `$(document).on('click', '[data-catid]', function() { //... the function... });` directly... Instead of defining the function out of the event handler.

Comment: I got it working like this, thank you